# Why my buttons (Login and Logout) aren't switching when session is logged in and redirecting to previous is also not working?

Tags: php, html, session

I'm new to the PHP to understand SESSIONS and building an E-commerce site which I shouldn't and now facing issues with very small doubts like

1. I'm trying to switch the login and logout buttons in header.php depending on the user's login status.
2. Also, I'm trying to redirect the user to the previous page after the successful login.But what I'm achieving is a server error which says in a different page.

I would appreciate if you can review my code and help me out with these two issues.

Thank you in advance.

> This is my Header.php

```
<?php
Session_start();
    $_SESSION['redirectURL']=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ECOM Site</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="Sliders.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header-top">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left  collapse navbar-collapse" id="12345">
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="Search">
                              <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <!--    <button class="btn btn-default submit" type="button" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style = "color : #e98fa0;"></i></button>-->
                                <a class="btn btn-default submit" role="button" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style = "color : #e98fa0;"></i></a>
                              </span>
                            </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 logo text-center ">
                            <a href="index.php">LOGO</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <div class="login-bars collapse navbar-collapse">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default log-button" >Sign Up</button>
                                <?php 
                                    if(  isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
                                        echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default log-button" name="logout" >Logout</button>';
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default log-button" ><a href="Login Page.php">Login</a></button>';
                                        function logout (){
                                            session_destroy();
                                        }
                                        if(isset($_POST['logout'])) { 
                                            logout(); 
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default log-button" >Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="header-botom">
                <div class="content white">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default nav-menu" role="navigation">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse " >
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">LOGO</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <!--/.navbar-header-->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapse-pdng " id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-font">
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Ear Rings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Jewelry </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div> 
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> This is my Login Page.php

```
<?php
Include ('header.php');
    include ('includes/connect.php');
    if( ! isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['email'] , $_POST['password']))
        {
                $username = $_POST['email'];
                $password = md5($_POST['password']);
                if(empty($username) or empty($password))
                {
                    $error = "Please fill all the fields";
                }
                else
                {
                    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE name = ? AND password = ? ");
                    $query->bindValue ( 1, $username);
                    $query->bindValue ( 2, $password);
                    $query->execute();
                    $num=$query->rowCount();

                if($num==1) {
                    $_SESSION['logged_in']= true;
                    header('location :' .$_SESSION['redirectURL']);
                    //header('location: index.php');
                    exit();
                }
                else{
                    $error = "Please enter correct Username and Password";
                }
            }
    }
}
else{
    $error = "you have already logged in";
}
?>
 <div class="login">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="login-grids">
                    <div class="col-md-6 log">
                             <h3>Login</h3>
                             <div class="strip"></div>
                             <p>Welcome, please enter the following to continue.</p>
                             <form action="" method="post">
                                <?php if(isset($error)){ ?>
                                        <small style = "color : #aa0000"; ><?php echo $error ?></small>
                                        <br><br>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email"  class="head">Email</label>
                                    <input class="form-control login-box" name="email"  type="text" id="email"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password"  class="head">Password</label>
                                    <input class="form-control login-box" name="password"  type="password" id="password"/>
                                </div>          
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn login-btn">Submit</button>
                             </form>
                            <a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 login-right">
                            <h3>New Registration</h3>
                            <div class="strip"></div>
                            <p>By creating an account with our store, you will be able to move through the checkout process faster, store multiple shipping addresses, view and track your orders in your account and more.</p>
                            <a href="register.html" class="button">Create An Account</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

> Or may be in the first place it's not logging in.

Comment: casing `$_Session` in `Header.php` variables are case sensitive.  Doah....

Answer (score 3):

In Header.php you have this

```
           <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="login-bars collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default log-button" >Sign Up</button>
                            <?php 
                                if(  isset($_Session['logged_in'])){
                                    echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default log-button" name="logout" >Logout</button>';
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default log-button" ><a href="Login Page.php">Login</a></button>';
                                    function logout (){
                                        session_destroy();
                                    }
                                    if(isset($_POST['logout'])) { 
                                        logout(); 
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default log-button" >Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Specifically

```
    $_Session
```

Should be

```
     $_SESSION
```

PHP variables are case sensitive, causing this to not be set under any condition.  Simple mistake.

Same is true in Page.php

```
    Include ('header.php');  //cassing ( probably ok here, looks bad though )
    include ('includes/connect.php');
    if( ! isset($_Session['logged_in'])) //same issue
          ....
```

Also be aware that filenames are case sensitive on Linux only!  `include ('header.php');`  will not include `Header.php` on linux, but will work on Windows.  I mention this as I see in your Post this could be a potential future issue, unless it's just a sloppy typo in the post.

These are easy for me to spot, because I have done the same thing literately millions of times...  So no worriers.

Last thing is with include, I prefer not using the `(` `)` as in `include 'header.php';` because include is a language construct and not a function, but it will work that way.  I'm just picky sometimes...

UPDATE: for the header redirect you are including the `header.php` file before the redirect, and that file contains output which wont work to well.  you can not output anything before calling the `header(..)` function.  That will give you a PHP warning, and will not do the redirect.

```
   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at  ... )
```

To fix this you might be able to simply move the `header.php` include to after the header code, but you will have to start the session at the top of both files you can check if a session is started by checking the session_id

```
  if( empty(session_id()) ) session_start();
```

If that becomes an issue ( in truth I haven't setup my own session handlers in about 5 years! ) so...

If you had error reporting turned on you would see this

```
<?php
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: @ArtisticPheonix Thankyou. but still when I click on the submit button it showing me an error same as before ( Which says Server error in different page) but when click on the back button it is logged in ..

is there any mistake in this line of code 
 ` header('location :' .$_SESSION['redirectURL']);`

Comment: And also do I need Ajax or something for dynamically switching button. Because when click on logout button it's working fine but only switching when I reload the page.

Comment: I don't see code for `logout()` but I imagine it also has a redirect that is also failing due to output before the header call.

Comment: You can see it in header.php in the form.

Answer (score 2):

first of all

```
Session_start();
```

will be

```
session_start();
```

and all the `$_Session` needs to be converted to `$_SESSION['logged_in];`

Comment: Oddly, function names are not case sensitive.  Though it is good practice to follow the convention in the manual for the function name.